# In touch with a professor of a college I am applying to. I haven't mentioned his research work in my statement of purpose?

Tags: application, professorship, statement-of-purpose, research-assistantship

I am applying to College A where I found the research work done by two labs (Lab X and Lab Y) interesting. I emailed the professors heading these labs two months ago and I did not get a reply from either of them. As a result, I emailed a few of the PhD students working for these labs and I managed to get a reply from one PhD student of Lab Y. Since I was able to discuss the ongoing research work and possible openings with the Ph.D. student, I expressed my interest in working with Lab Y in my SOP and sent my application last week to the college.

Yesterday, I receive an email from Lab X's professor saying that he is interested in taking me in and will look out for my application. While this could have been good news, I have not mentioned Lab X's research at all in my SOP. Would this antagonize the professor and have an adverse impact on my application?

Comment: I didn't down or up vote your question, I only edited a typo in your question. I am innocent of what you accuse me, I swear.

Comment: You welcome, no worries,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the more relevant question at this point is - is there really anything you can do about it?  The short answer here is "no" - so don't worry too much about it (I know, easy to say, hard to do). To answer your question: could it antagonize Prof X?  Sure, but their reaction isn't under your control.  And if the follow-up question is, "should I contact them?" - no, other than to continue expressing interest in the lab's work.  Beyond that, there's no need to mention that they weren't included in your SOP.

A word of advice for the future though - if you're interested in working with a particular lab, don't worry about whether or not you've heard back from them. Just list them in your SOP anyways - best case scenario, they send you a message; worst case scenario, nothing happens.  You've got nothing to lose by including them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So could this lead to an application rejection since it could antagonize professor X?

Comment: @tr_quest: Sure it could - but it might also not matter.  The point is that there's no real way of knowing what Prof X will think, unfortunately, so I doubt anyone can answer your question definitively (I apologize if that comes across as harsh, it's not meant to).  Here's a question for you though - if Prof X gets offended because you didn't mention them in your SOP, you may not really want to work under them in the first place.  Finding an adviser is about more than just the research - it's about finding a mentor who can support you and teach you.

Comment: To add to your second paragraph, the middle scenario is that you don't hear back from them, but they still read your application, either because they read all of them, or someone recommends it to them as the interests are similar

Comment: @tr_quest I mean the professor you sent the email to who did not respond.  You may not hear back from the professor, but it is still possible the professor will see your application materials.